# Getting two different values for CurrentCulture in same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web, cultureinfo

I have multiple projects in my solution: I have a WebApi project named "Api" that has a reference to a class library named "Models". I am setting the globalization information in my web config like this:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en"/>
```

I have some resources (.resx) files on my "Models" project and my problem is that I am getting the spanish version of the translated strings. If I debug and set a breakpoint in this line at the "Api" project:

```
var a = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

I am getting the value "en-GB", but if I set a similar line and breakpoint in the "Models" project, I get "es-Es".
What I am doing wrong? How can I fix this? I would ideally keep the language configuration in my web config (since I have many transformations for multiple environments). Thank you very much

EDIT: I have another class library similar to "Models" called "Services" which I am also referencing from "Api. I checked there and CultureInfo.CurrentCulture as well as CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture equals "en-GB" so I am guessing It could be something related to the project configuration?

Comment: Check `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`. I suppose your web confit entry only affects this one.

Comment: I checked, I set <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/> and I am getting CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = "en-US" and CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = "es-ES" so it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that the "Models" code was executing in a different thread, so I removed the globalization info from web config and replaced it with

```
<add key="LanguageCode" value="es" />
```

Ant then on the Startup.Cs of my "Api" project i wrote:

```
 CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LanguageCode"]);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

And this seems to work correctly.